# Blocking event throws an ArgumentException

Tags: c, argumentexception

I am doing a serial-encapsulated class and want to get back after sending the data.
But blocking waiting for a return causes an ArgumentException error.

Run in winform to make sure the parameters are correct, but it seems that blocking events will be triggered.
include:
EventWaitHandle.WaitOne(3000,false);
SerialPort.Read();
And there is a call to C++ to write Dll, will it be written to the protected memory caused by?

```
//Raise the error
//Adopted two methods
//one,EventWaitHandle ,The serialPort.DataReceived event fires when _waitHandle.Set();
serialPort.Write(buf, 0, buf.Length);
_waitHandle.WaitOne(3000, false);

//Two 
serialPort.ReadTimeout = 3000;
serialPort.Write(buf, 0, buf.Length);
serialPort.Read(buf, 0, 4);
```

The interesting thing is that every time it is the third timeout, it will report an error. The try cannot be caught. The prompt will automatically exit the program after the exception is thrown. The TimeoutException timeout can be caught.
And if you don't block, don't return, you won't get an error.

Thank you for your answer, sorry for not writing clearly. The serialport is a communication with a coin acceptor, and Dll is another package for canon camera communication.
Today when testing the shutdown program, I found that the video stream Stream of the canon prompts ArgumentException. Because serialPort and canon are two different threads each performing different tasks, so the problem should be determined here.

```
private void SDK_LiveViewUpdated(UnmanagedMemoryStream img)
{
Evf_Bmp?.Dispose();
Evf_Bmp = new Bitmap(img);//ArgumentException
}
```

So serialport and canon are different threads, why serialport blocking causes an argument of UnonMemoryStream of canon
And every time it is blocked for the third time, ArgumentException?

Comment: C doesn't have exceptions. Is this C++ or Arduino code? Please tag appropriately

Comment: Thank you for your answer, the question has been added